# Eliminating overflow-y jump in DIV element

Tags: html, css

Have a `div` element fixed to the side of my webpage with a bunch of years in it. It has `overflow-y: hidden` for default and then, on `:hover`, `overflow-y: auto`.

When I mouse over the element, all the content bumps to the left 17px (width of scrollbar) because of it being centered.

I've looked for a solution and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417934/how-to-prevent-scrollbar-from-repositioning-web-page) on The Stack, but the solutions only apply to problems involving the entire window.

CSS posted below, the relevant HTML only has the DIV container and .year elements but if you want it I can throw it up here as well. Pic comparison isn't centered properly but still shows the issue.

[image]

```css
.sideBar {
  background-color: #ff9900;
  height: 150px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
.sideBar:hover {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.year, .h2year {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1em 0;
}
.year:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="sideBar" id="yearsBar">
  <div>
    <h2 class="h2year">Years</h2>
    <p class="year" id="2015">2015</p>
    <p class="year" id="2014">2014</p>
    <p class="year" id="2013">2013</p>
    <p class="year" id="2012">2012</p>
    <p class="year" id="2011">2011</p>
    <p class="year" id="2010">2010</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add your HTML to the code snippet as well? Otherwise nothing shows up when you run it.

Comment: HTML included, my bad. Forgot about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an inner wrapper (you already had a `div`). Then,

- Set the desired height to the outer wrapper and the desired width to the inner one.
- Display the outer wrapper as an inline-block, in order to make it shrink to the size of its content.
- Hide the overflow on the outer wrapper. Use `overflow-y: scroll` at `:hover`.

```css
#outer-wrapper {
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}
#outer-wrapper:hover {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
#inner-wrapperv {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```css
.sideBar {
  background-color: #ff9900;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}
.sideBar:hover {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.sideBar > div {
  width: 200px;
}
.year, .h2year {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1em 0;
}
.year:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="sideBar" id="yearsBar">
  <div>
    <h2 class="h2year">Years</h2>
    <p class="year" id="2015">2015</p>
    <p class="year" id="2014">2014</p>
    <p class="year" id="2013">2013</p>
    <p class="year" id="2012">2012</p>
    <p class="year" id="2011">2011</p>
    <p class="year" id="2010">2010</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

At least, it works on Firefox, Chrome and IE8.

Comment: great one. Thanks