# how do i fix one page of my website from shifting a few pixels?

Tags: html, css

The main page of my website is http://jennladermandesigns.com and the page that shifts to the left is http://jennladermandesigns.com/portfolio. I have looked at all parts of both pages and compared them against one another and nothing is different between the 2 pages. I also found that the shifting was only occuring in older versions of browsers

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "shifting a few pixels?"

Comment: What is shifting? I see that on the portfolio the content is getting pushed down because the portfolio has that submenu.

Comment: incomplete question. you must provide more details about  the 'shifting'

Comment: The "work" page does not have a scroll bar on the side, whereas the other pages do. The layout adjusting to this is causing the shift. Try zooming out so that all the content fits on one page, then compare.

Comment: The fix, I suppose, would be to make sure the whole page fits in the window, or to set `overflow-y` to either `scroll` or `none` on all pages (in the case of `none` you'll need to figure out some other way to show overflow).

Comment: Find your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417934/how-to-prevent-scrollbar-from-repositioning-web-page

Comment: thank you everyone, @kevinboucher the code worked

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS:

```
html { overflow-y: scroll; }
```

This will leave space for the scrollbar even when it is not required.