# How can I prevent the page shifting when scrollbar is disabled

Tags: css

I'm disabling the scroll-bar in some cases using:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

But, whenever my scrollbar is disabled, the page shifts to the right a little. So is there a way to avoid that shifting?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417934/how-to-prevent-scrollbar-from-repositioning-web-page

Comment: @sweaver2112 I can't disable the scrolling with overflow-y: scroll; 
But I want to disable the scrolling which is achieved by overflow: hidden;