# My Web Content Shifts Left When The Vertical Scrollbar Appears on windows machine... how to fix this?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using overflow-y:auto, it works fine on mac but not on windows machine.
I also tried using overflow-y: overlay, but many browsers does not support this and also its a deprecated property. Is there a simple and reliable solution to this.

Comment: If you can use javascript, you can try to detect the browser via useragent and load a different stylesheet for different browsers. You can also try to style the scrollbar itself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent scrollbar from repositioning web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417934/how-to-prevent-scrollbar-from-repositioning-web-page)